# I think of him as family

Tags: sentence-construction

> It's a family business , it's fun to get to go do all these things together, and I love it .
>   You look at my daughter, my wife , and now my brother is now building all my fan lights and fan lamps , and it seems only fitting that my dad would have to help as well , being that he started the whole thing with a light that I made for him .
>   It's family , outside of Bill , but **I think of him as family** because , good grief , I've been stuck with him for 30 years , you know , so he's almost family .

I wonder how one person can be referred to with a word that represents a group of people .
 Is this common ? if so could you give me an example ?

can I say : "I think of him as a family member" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to someone as "family" is common and idiomatic. Used this way, it always means a member of your own family. All of the following are acceptable:

> I think of him as family.
>
> I see him and his wife as family.
>
> Do you think of him as family?
>
> He's like family to you.
>
> We're all family here.

The usage carries the implication that the person is not only related to you by blood, but that you have a close bond or at least an unbreakable obligation to them.

As for why it works grammatically—that's an interesting question. This is only my analysis, but I think "family" is being treated as uncountable. For an analogy, it would also be fine to look at a slice of bread and say "this is bread," even though the slice is part of a whole. I'd love to hear some other perspectives though.